# Elasticsearch query with multiple exact avlues

Tags: elasticsearch

For a bool query, I could get results with the following:

```
POST _search
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "city":  "LA" }},
        { "match": { "employee_id" : 123}}
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I pass the it a list of employee_id's like this `"employee_id" : [123, 234, 345]` for `{ "match": { "city":  "LA" }` . ? Basically I want to retrieve documents for employee_id `123, 234, 345` whose `city = 'LA'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-term-query.html) filter to find single exact-match terms, and [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to find documents which match at least *n* of a list of terms.

If you don't need document ranking (which you don't when doing exact term matches, since the documents would all score the same), use [filtered queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) to improve query performance.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "city": "LA"
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "employee_id": [ 123, 456, 789 ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```